# checking status of process with subprocess.Popen in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

If I invoke a process with `subprocess.Popen` in Python as follows:

`myproc = subprocess.Popen(...).communicate()`

what is the correct way to see its status? Not its output to stdout or stderr, but its exit status once it's finished (e.g. 0 for success or another for failure)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`returncode` is indeed the answer, but the solution doesn't need to be complicated.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(...)
stdoutdata, stderrdata = process.communicate()
print process.returncode
```

More info in the [Python `subprocess` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode).

Comment: is ``wait`` really required or does ``communicate()`` take of things when the process is still running?

Comment: @user248237 The docs say "return code, set by `poll()` and `wait()` (and indirectly by `communicate()`)." So `communicate()` should take care of waiting for the process to end.

Answer (score 10):

A process doesn't have a return code until it's finished executing. Therefore, if it hasn't yet finished, you have to decide what you want to do: wait for it, or return some indicator of "I haven't finished yet".

If you want to wait, use [`communicate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) and then check the `returncode` attribute.

If you want to check whether the return code is set, and return `None` if not, use [`Popen.poll()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll).

> Popen.poll()
>
> Check if child process has terminated. Set and return returncode attribute.

(if process hasn't terminated, `poll()` returns `None`)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to call a `wait` on your subprocess and then (once is done) check the status in the `returncode` field of the subprocess instance.

I have a little routine that calls stuff, maybe it'll help...

```
def singleProcessExecuter(command, ** kwargs):
    assert isinstance(command, list), "Expected 'command' parameter to be a list containing the process/arguments to execute. Got %s of type %s instead" % (command, type(command))
    assert len(command) > 0, "Received empty list of parameters"
    retval = {
            "exitCode": -1,
            "stderr": u"",
            "stdout": u"",
            "execTime": datetime.timedelta(0),
            "command": None,
            "pid": None
            }
    retval["command"] = command
    log.info("::singleProcessExecuter > At %s, executing \"%s\"" % (datetime.datetime.now(), " ".join(command)))
    #print("::singleProcessExecuter > At %s, executing \"%s\"" % (datetime.datetime.now(), " ".join(parameter)))
    cwd = kwargs.get("cwd", os.getcwd())
    user = kwargs.get("user", getUid())
    sheel = kwargs.get("shell", False)
    startDatetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    myPopy = subprocess.Popen(command, cwd=cwd, preexec_fn=os.seteuid(getUid(user)), shell=sheel, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    retval["pid"] = myPopy.pid
    log.debug("::singleProcessExecuter > Command \"%s\" got pid %s" % (" ".join(command), myPopy.pid))
    try:
        retval["stdout"], retval["stderr"] = myPopy.communicate()
        myPopy.wait()
    except OSError, osErr:
        log.debug("::singleProcessExecuter > Got %s %s in myPopy.communicate() when trying get output of command %s. It is probably a bug (more info: http://bugs.python.org/issue1731717)" % (osErr, type(osErr), command[0]))
    except Exception, e:
        log.warn("::singleProcessExecuter > Got %s %s when trying to get stdout/stderr outputs of %s" % (type(e), e, " ".join(command)))
        log.debug("::singleProcessExecuter > Got %s %s when trying to get stdout/stderr outputs of %s. Showing traceback:\n%s" % (type(e), e, " ".join(command), traceback.format_exc()))
        raise
    retval["exitCode"] = myPopy.returncode
    retval["execTime"] = datetime.datetime.now() - startDatetime
    #print(":singleProcessExecuter > This is %s's retval:\n%s" % (" ".join(parameter), retval)) 
    return retval
```

You can try it with:

```
print "This is the return: %s" % singleProcessExecuter(["ls", "-la"])
```

Comment: I really like your code! I know it's been a few years, but I'd be glad to see the needed imports for that!