# Is there a way to check if a subprocess is still running?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm launching a number of subprocesses with `subprocess.Popen` in Python.
I'd like to check whether one such process has completed. I've found two ways of checking the status of a subprocess, but both seem to force the process to complete.
One is using `process.communicate()` and printing the returncode, as explained here: [checking status of process with subprocess.Popen in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043030/checking-status-of-process-with-subprocess-popen-in-python).
Another is simply calling `process.wait()` and checking that it returns 0.

Is there a way to check if a process is still running without waiting for it to complete if it is?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

> **Ouestion**: ... a way to check if a process is still running ...

You can do it for instance:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(...
"""
A None value indicates that the process hasn't terminated yet.
"""
poll = p.poll()
if poll is None:
  # p.subprocess is alive
```

[Python » 3.6.1 Documentation popen-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects)

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***

Comment: I can do p.poll(). This returns None even after the process is done. I know this because the script I call produces an output file which appears, and still this returns None.
Also, I can print p.wait() which gives 0, but printing p.poll() afterwards still gives None.

Comment: It Also Works With Python 2.7.10

Comment: I was having a problem with this solution at first because I was using p.poll immediately after p.terminate and still getting None. Adding a small delay between the two fixed this. Hope this helps if anyone else is having this issue.

Comment: It is really important to note that this method will only work with a time.sleep value before polling for the subprocess, else it will always say that the process is running. In my case, a value of 5 seconds was good enough.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll

Comment: `if p.poll():` will not qualify, because `p.returncode` is 0 (in good scenario) and `bool(0) is False`. So use `if p.poll() is not None:` to make sure that process finished his work.

Answer (score 9):

Doing the

```
myProcessIsRunning = poll() is None
```

As suggested by the main answer, is the recommended way and the simplest way to check if a process running. (and it works in jython as well)

If you do not have the process instance in hand to check it.
Then use the operating system TaskList / Ps processes.

On windows, my command will look as follows:

```
filterByPid = "PID eq %s" % pid
        pidStr = str(pid)
        commandArguments = ['cmd', '/c', "tasklist", "/FI", filterByPid, "|", "findstr",  pidStr ]
```

This is essentially doing the same thing as the following command line:

```
cmd /c "tasklist /FI "PID eq 55588" | findstr 55588"
```

And on linux, I do exactly the same using the:

```
pidStr = str(pid)
commandArguments = ['ps', '-p', pidStr ]
```

The ps command will already be returning error code 0 / 1 depending on whether the process is found. While on windows you need the find string command.

This is the same approach that is discussed on the following stack overflow thread:

[Verify if a process is running using its PID in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460775/verify-if-a-process-is-running-using-its-pid-in-java)

NOTE:
If you use this approach, remember to wrap your command call in a try/except:

```
try:
    foundRunningProcess = subprocess.check_output(argumentsArray, **kwargs)
    return True
except Exception as err:
    return False
```

Note, be careful if you are developing with VS Code and using pure Python and Jython.
On my environment, I was under the illusion that the poll()  method did not work because a process that I suspected that must have ended was indeed running.
This process had launched Wildfly. And after I had asked for wildfly to stop, the shell was still waiting for user to  "Press any key to continue . . .".

In order to finish off this process, in pure python the following code was working:

```
process.stdin.write(os.linesep)
```

On jython, I had to fix this code to look as follows:

```
print >>process.stdin, os.linesep
```

And with this difference the process did indeed finish.
And the jython.poll() started telling me that the process is indeed finished.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by the other answers `None` is the designed placeholder for the "return code" when no code has been returned yet by the subprocess.

The documentation for the [returncode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) attribute backs this up (emphasis mine):

> The child return code, set by `poll()` and `wait()` (and indirectly by `communicate()`). A `None` value indicates that **the process hasn’t terminated yet**.
>
> A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (POSIX only).

An interesting place where this `None` value occurs is when using the `timeout` parameter for [wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) or [communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

> If the process does not terminate after timeout seconds, a `TimeoutExpired` exception will be raised.

If you catch that exception and check the returncode attribute it will indeed be `None`

```
import subprocess
with subprocess.Popen(['ping','127.0.0.1']) as p:
    try:
        p.wait(timeout=3)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        assert p.returncode is None
```

If you look at the source for subprocess you can see the exception being raised.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47be7d0108b4021ede111dbd15a095c725be46b7/Lib/subprocess.py#L1930-L1931

If you search that source for `self.returncode is` you'll find many uses where the library authors lean on that `None` return code design to infer if an app is running or not running. The `returncode` attribute is [initialized](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47be7d0108b4021ede111dbd15a095c725be46b7/Lib/subprocess.py#L806) to `None` and only ever changes in a few spots, the main flow in invocations to `_handle_exitstatus` to pass on the actual return code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind installing comtypes (pure Python), you can use this one (tested against Python 3.10 / Windows 10):

```
import subprocess
from time import perf_counter

import comtypes.client


def is_process_alive(pid):
    WMI = comtypes.client.CoGetObject("winmgmts:")
    processes = WMI.InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
    if [True for pp in processes if pp.Properties_("ProcessID").Value == pid]: # checks all pids there are
        return True
    return False


p = subprocess.Popen("ping 8.8.8.8", shell=True)

start = perf_counter()
while is_process_alive(p.pid):
    print(f"{p.pid} is alive", end="\r")
print(f"{p.pid} is not alive - execution time: {perf_counter()-start}")

start = perf_counter()
p = subprocess.Popen("ping 8.8.8.8", shell=False)
while is_process_alive(p.pid):
    print(f"{p.pid} is alive", end="\r")
print(f"{p.pid} is not alive - execution time: {perf_counter()-start}")

#output
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=119
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=119
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=119
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=119
Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 9ms, Maximum = 11ms, Average = 9ms
18404 is not alive - execution time: 3.170662900000025
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=119
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=119
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=119
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=119
Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 9ms, Maximum = 10ms, Average = 9ms
6788 is not alive - execution time: 3.1898495000023104
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use subprocess.check_output to have a look at your output.

Try this code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['your command here'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: sorry, this doesn't help. it just create buffer overflow