# Prevent python script from running if another one is being executed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two scripts inside a bigger system I'm developing. Lets call one `foo.py` and the other one `bar.py`.

`foo` creates files that `bar` will afterwards read and delete. Now, if `foo` is running and working on a file, `bar` will mess things up by working on the same file before `foo` is finished.

`foo` and `bar` get started automatically by other stuff, not manually by someone that runs them. **How can I make sure that, if `foo` is working on a file, `bar` will not start?**

I have thought about editing both of them so that `foo` writes a 1 to a text file at the beginning of the execution and a 0 when it finishes, and to make `bar` read the text file to check wheter it can start. But I'm not really sure this is the most elegant solution, and also I don't want to block `bar` if `foo` ever fails in the middle of execution, leaving the file at 1.

Comment: Can't you execute foo in a subprocess and make bar wait for foo to finish (by success or fail) using `Popen.poll()`? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/43274476/2923755

Comment: Have you looked into file locking?

Comment: Newbie here, haven't header about subprocesses  or file locking. Gonna do my own research, but, could you guys point to any good sources?

Comment: @PabloM start by searching for `Popen`. There you will find info on both `subprocess` and `poll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess`

In your main file:

```
import subprocess


def main():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'foo.py'])
    res = p.wait()
    if res == 0:
        print("foo did ok")
        # execute bar.py
    else:
        print("foo failed along the way")
```

In foo.py, make sure to exit with code 0 if everything went fine:
`exit(0)` (this will be returned to `res` in main script).

You can also use `poll()` if you want to do other stuff while waiting for `foo` to finish.

```
def main():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'foo.py'])

    while not p.poll()==0:
        print("wait for foo")
        #do some other magic. but make sure to have a break condition
        # e.g. if foo takes too long.
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible strategy :

- `foo` build `todo.foo`.
- it renames it `todo.bar` when done.
- `bar` look after `todo.bar`, compute it and delete it when done.

Comment: Isn't this the same as his "write 1 then 0" strategy? If foo fails here, bar is "blocked" but by not seeing the file

Comment: You are right you just have one less file to manage. but if foo fails, is it a good idea that bar uses it ?

Comment: Exactly my thought also LOL, but that's what he wants hehe

Answer (score 0):

```
import fcntl

pid_file = 'mysoftware.pid'
fp = open(pid_file, 'w')
try:
    fcntl.lockf(fp, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
except IOError:
    # another instance is running
    print("already running")
    sys.exit(1)
```

this works for me.