# How to delete Files / Directories after Subprocess is done with them?

Tags: python, python-2.7, watchdog

I am using [Watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) to monitor a directory. If any new directories are added, I want to start subprocesses on those "Source" directories and call a program `anon_local` on the directories which will output some files.

My question is: What would be an elegant way of deleting the directories and their content after my subprocesses are done with that directory?

```
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory and event.event_type == 'created':
            PATH = event.src_path
            proc = subprocess.Popen(["python2", "anon_local.py" , PATH, "-t", "target directory", "-csv", "arg", "-p", "arg"])
```

Comment: Can you use a [TemporaryDirectory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html)?

Comment: @ndmeiri I would prefer avoiding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)'s [`rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) function.

So long as `PATH` is the directory you want deleted, just check to make sure your subprocess has finished, and then just run `shutil.rmtree(PATH)`

If you need to wait until your subprocess is done, you can accomplish this by calling `.poll()` on your `proc` and waiting for it to return `None`. For example:

```
while proc.poll() == None:  # .poll() will return a value once it's complete. 
    time.sleep(1)
[then remove your directory here]
```

Comment: Ah! I am assuming (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274476/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-subprocess-is-still-running) would be the way to go about checking if process is still running!

Comment: @TheOne yes. i just update my answer to show a way to wait until the subprocess is done before removing your directory.