# How do i know if a subprocess has started or not?

Tags: python

I have the following subprocess.

```
ss = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "-m", "unittest", totest], 
                      stdin=None, 
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  
                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I want to know if it has started or it had thrown errors.

Comment: I think the process is started right away, as OS schedules it. You can check if it is ended or not using something like `subprocess.poll` or `subprocess.communicate`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if a subprocess is still running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274476/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-subprocess-is-still-running)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate of that. The other question asks if the process still runs. This one asks if the process already runs.

Comment: @glglgl Yes, I asked that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the call returns normally, you can consider the process started. If the process cannot start for any reason, the `Popen()` call throws an exception.