# How to encapsulate running a process in Python with realtime + to-variable output capture and return code capture?

Tags: python, terminal, command-line, automation, subprocess

> Note: I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043030/checking-status-of-process-with-subprocess-popen-in-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750468/displaying-subprocess-output-to-stdout-and-redirecting-it), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344932/python-subprocess-call-stdout-to-file-stderr-to-file-display-stderr-on-scree) question. While there is much useful info, none give an exact answer. My knowledge of the language is limited, so I cannot put together pieces from those answers in a way that fit the needed use case (especially point (4) below).

I am looking for a way to run a process with a given set of arguments in current Python (latest version atm is 3.11), with the following requirements:

1. The stderr and stdout of the process are displayed in real-time, as they would be if run directly (or through a script) in almost any shell, i.e. `bash` or `PowerShell`
2. Both streams are also separately captured into a string or byte array for accessing later
3. The return code is captured on process finish
4. This is encapsualted in a function that simply requires the argument list, and returns an object containing both streams and the return code

*All points except for (1)* are covered by `subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True)`. So, I need to define a function

```py
def run_and_output_realtime:
    # ???
    return result
```

Which would allow to change *just the first line* of code like

```py
run_tool_result = subproccess.run(args, capture_output=True)
if run_tool_result.returncode != 0:
    if "Unauthorized" in run_tool_result.stderr.decode():
        print("Please check authorization")
else:
    if "Duration" in run_tool_result.stdout.decode():
        # parse to get whatever duration was in the output
```

To `run_tool_result = run_and_output_realtime(args)`, and have all the remaining lines unchanged and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would hopefully solve your (1). Tested it on Python 3.11.

```
import subprocess
import sys
from typing import List, Tuple, NamedTuple

class ProcessResult(NamedTuple):
    stdout: bytes
    stderr: bytes
    returncode: int

def run_and_output_realtime(args: List[str]) -> ProcessResult:
    stdout_lines = []
    stderr_lines = []
    
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        args,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True,
        bufsize=1,
    )

    # Read stdout and stderr line by line
    while process.poll() is None:
        stdout_line = process.stdout.readline()
        stderr_line = process.stderr.readline()

        if stdout_line:
            sys.stdout.write(stdout_line)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            stdout_lines.append(stdout_line)
        
        if stderr_line:
            sys.stderr.write(stderr_line)
            sys.stderr.flush()
            stderr_lines.append(stderr_line)

    # Capture remaining stdout and stderr lines
    stdout_remaining = process.stdout.readlines()
    stderr_remaining = process.stderr.readlines()
    stdout_lines.extend(stdout_remaining)
    stderr_lines.extend(stderr_remaining)

    process.stdout.close()
    process.stderr.close()
    
    stdout = "".join(stdout_lines).encode()
    stderr = "".join(stderr_lines).encode()
    
    return ProcessResult(stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, returncode=process.returncode)
```